# Issues inserting html on custom toolbar button in summernote

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am trying to add 2 custom buttons in the summernote toolbar, 1 to simply add a line break, the other to insert some text with a small style.  When I use the buttons, it cleans the html, and doesn't perform the desired outcome (line break or inserting small text).  How can I insert the html from the toolbar selection and have it not be altered?

Here is the button rendering jQuery:

```js
var BR_Button = function (context) {
  var ui = $.summernote.ui;

  // create button
  var button = ui.button({
    contents: 'BR',
    tooltip: 'Line Break',
    click: function () {
      // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
      context.invoke('editor.insertText', '<br/>');
    }
  });

  return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
}

var Small_Button = function (context) {
  var ui = $.summernote.ui;

  // create button
  var button = ui.button({
    contents: 'small',
    tooltip: 'Small Style Emphasis',
    click: function () {
      // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
      context.invoke('editor.insertText', '<small>small text</small>');
    }
  });

  return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
}
```

And the toolbar customization code:

```js
$('#id_text').summernote({
  toolbar: [
  ['paragraph', ['paragraph']],
  ['fontsize', ['style','fontname','fontsize','height']],
  ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
  ['font', ['small','strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
  ['color', ['color']],
  ['para', ['BR','ul', 'ol',]],
  ['insert', ['table','link','picture','video','hr']],
  ['codeview', ['codeview']],
  ],
  focus: true,
  buttons: {
    small: Small_Button,
    BR: BR_Button
    }
  });
```

The issue is that when I hit the BR button in the toolbar, it inserts <br/>, not giving me an actual line break..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 'editor.insertText', use 'editor.pasteHTML' and this allows inserting of the html rather than forcing safe characters.

var BR_Button = function (context) {
  var ui = $.summernote.ui;

// create button
  var button = ui.button({
    contents: '**BR**',
    tooltip: 'Insert Line Break',
    click: function () {
      // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
      context.invoke('editor.pasteHTML', '
');
    }
  });

Comment: I am getting error when click on button Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined